# adding Array variables into a list of array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray

I am having three array variables from different array list , how to add them  and place them in a single array list.i.e suppose if abc is from array list 1,pqr from array list2 and xyz from array list3 , after adding into new list arraylist 4 should have abc,pqr,xyz

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, just do:

```
NSMutableArray *newArray = [NSMutableArray array];
[newArray addObjectsFromArray:array1];
[newArray addObjectsFromArray:array2];
[newArray addObjectsFromArray:array3];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below method of `NSMutableArray`.

```
- (void)addObjectsFromArray:(NSArray *)otherArray
```

**otherArray :** An array of objects to add to the end of the receiving array’s content.

See in [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

I assume **list1,list2,list3** is either the type of `NSArray` OR `NSMutableArray`.

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[myArray addObjectsFromArray:list1];
[myArray addObjectsFromArray:list2];
[myArray addObjectsFromArray:list3];
```

Comment: hey i have a table view with 3 rows, if i select the first row , the item on the first row get saved in a array variable say arrdata , silmilarly when i select 2nd and 3rd row , i want it to get saved in the same variable arrData

Comment: @sameer : Did you create the arrData array  ?

Comment: ya i have created arrData as extern const NSMutableArray